Strict versus weak Gray tensor product
For two strict $(\infty,\infty)$-categories $C$, $D$
one can consider the strict lax Gray tensor product $C \otimes_\text{strict} D$.
Similarly, for two weak $(\infty,\infty)$-categories $C$, $D$
one can consider the weak version of lax Gray tensor product $C \otimes D$.
Moreover for every strict $(\infty, \infty)$-categories $C$, $D$ one can construct a comparison functor $C \otimes D \to C\otimes_\text{strict} D$.
Is it known under which conditions on $C$, $D$ this comparison functor is an equivalence?
For example is the comparison functor an equivalence if $C$, $D$ are gaunt or (strong) Steiner?

It’s an equivalence if they are strong Steiner — I showed this here (I note in there that the strong Steiner complexes form what I call a "monoidally suitable site", and I show in there that the strict Gray tensor product on a monoidally suitable site Day convolves / reflects up to the weak Gray tensor. So if $C$, $D$ are strong Steiner, then $C \otimes^\text{strict} D$ is the strictification of $C \otimes^\text{weak} D$, and it will suffice to show that $C \otimes^\text{weak} D$ is already strict. In turn, $C \otimes^\text{weak} D$ is the localization of $yC \otimes^{\text{Day convolution}} yD = y(C \otimes^\text{strict} D)$ at the localization described in the first link (where $y : \{\text{Strong Steiner}\} \to \operatorname{Psh}(\text{Strong Steiner})$ is the yoneda embedding). But the localization described is "subcanonical" — representables are already local (the main result here). So $C \otimes^\text{weak} D = C \otimes^\text{strict} D$ as desired.
As for gaunt things more generally, this is unknown. Haugseng conjectured this at least in dimension 2. In dimension 2, Maehara's model seems relevant, since it is also constructed by some kind of Day convolution up from a strict Gray tensor.

@ Tim Campion. Great! Thanks a lot! But one question: I guess the sub canonical localisation you refer to is the one $ Psh(Strong Steiner) \to Cat_\omega^f$  to flagged $\omega$-categories. I guess the localisation $ Psh(Strong Steiner) \to Cat_\omega$  to $\omega$-categories is not subcanonical, right? The Gray-tensor $C \otimes^{weak} D$ I consider is the Rezk-completion of the$C \otimes^{weak} D$ you consider, which you identify with $C \otimes^{strict} D$ if $C,D$ are strong Steiner.

If $C,D$ are additionally gaunt, I guess then $C \otimes^{strict} D$ is gaunt, too. This would imply that $C \otimes^{strict} D$ is already Rezk-complete and so computes the weak Gray tensor product of Rezk-complete $\omega$-categories. By the way how is the precise relationship between Strong Steiner and gaunt?

Ah yeah good point. Strong Steiner things (more generally, torsionfree complexes) are certainly gaunt but definitely not conversely. In fact, any finite dimensional computad is gaunt I suppose. (Though even infinite dimensional torsionfree complexes are gaunt)

Thanks a lot! Just to get a feeling: consider the 1-category _1/∂_1≅(ℕ), which has no automorphisms and so is gaunt and which is free on a graph. Is this a torsion free complex? I guess there is no problem with transitivity because there is only a single generating 1-cell.

Not a torsionfree complex. In a torsionfree complex, the forward and backward boundaries of an atom $\partial_+ a, \partial_- a$ are each given by finite sets of atoms one dimension lower, and these two sets are required to be disjoint (and more). The “loop” in $B \mathbb N$ is a great example of what “torsionfreeness” is designed to rule out.

I see, thanks a lot! But I guess torsionfree complexes like strong strong Steiner $\omega$-categories are inductive in the sense that for any torsionfree complex the $\omega$-category of morphisms between any two objects is again torsion-free?
